# Leverage browser caching code in .htaccess won't work

Tags: caching, browser, gtmetrix

I'm having an error on GTMetirx: Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

I have to leverage browser caching for png, jpg, woff2, gif, gzip, and js files but this code doesn't work:

```
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
```

But when I added the code and try to see if the error will be fixed, it's still showing the same error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's already resolved since all this time passed... 
But you can first check that mod_expires is enabled on your server.

Second you can check that your .htaccess is not overrided by a virtual host conf file. If you use virtual host for your domain then check in your virtual host config file that you don't have a parent directory (of the one with your expires header) with "Allowoverride All". This Allowoverride All means that the conf file override anything in the .htaccess file. Set Allowoverride to None or put your expires header in your conf file in the Directory section.

There are other ways to resolve this problem, these two points are not an exhaustive list. It's just how I solved this problem myself today. Hope it will help somebody.